# Fix horizontal scrolling

Tags: html, css, mobile

Trying to fix horizontal scrollbar on the page I'm building http://www.fotoimpuls.eu/, and can't figure out what might cause this issue...

The issue appears only on `max-width : 767px`, where the width of the `contentWrapper` is off for some reason, causing horizontal scrollbar to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, now i've seen it, it's better if we do this live via share screen because there are a number of things you need to do.

1. `section id="contact"` remove it's padding.
2. `@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) .postWrap .row {` remove padding.
3. Your markup is wrong I think, you placed four-col inside a four-col the error comes from that AFAIK.

or just use `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: Hmmm, that didn't fix the issue - I still get a gap on the right. The whole `<html>` width seems to be off for some reason, not filling the entire screen...

Comment: I see this in Firefox and on mobile: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2gwat1u&s=8#.VXnvA-dE-kw

Comment: Mozilla normal size: http://i.imgur.com/cCvZjU7.png - Mozilla Responsive: http://i.imgur.com/7eoZ1AQ.png